# Bootstrap and Angular Material conflict

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I'm almost done with building an Angular project and I need to have a confirmation dialogue , so I used Angular material for that .
Now the problem is it messed up my bootstrap styling in the whole project , I only need the confirmation dialogue from Angular Material , and it's not so practical that I restructure my whole project styling without bootstrap . what should I do about this situation?

Comment: Bootstrap has a modal window you could use to the same effect, meaning you could do away with Material completely. Is there some reason why you need the Material dialogue?

Comment: Do you import whole MaterialModule?

Comment: I just need a confirmation dialogue to confirm deletion of records and resetting of balances . I find it good as I can subscribe to It's output whether it was a click on YES button or NO button. that's it

Comment: Michal Lis I only imported  MatDialogModule ,MatButtonModule ,BrowserAnimationsModule in app.module , and I imported the css styling file in styles.css

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-component',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
  styleUrls: ['./your.component.scss']
})
```

Inside `your.component.scss`, on first line:

```
@import '~path/to/angular-material.css';
```

Now `angular-material.css` will be scoped to your component and won't apply to any other component in your project, not even to children of current component.

**Note**: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` is the default value, so you don't actually need it, but setting it to any other value will prevent scoping from working.

Read more about encapsulation [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation).

Comment: Now bootstrap styling is okay , but the confirmation dialogue's styling is messed

Comment: Are you expecting me to know what *"messed"* means for you? If you have subcomponents and want `angular-material.css` to apply to them, you could wrap the import into `::ng-deep { @import here... }`. But I don't know for sure if that's valid syntax. I mean, I ***know it's not*** in CSS, but the parser might understand it and parse it correctly.

Comment: @Omar, create a bootply or codesandbox and i'll have a look. Can't help more without seeing what you have. Make it minimal, for testing: one bootstrap styled component to make sure it's not getting affected and the dialogue.

Comment: No I don't have any subcomponents , it's just the dialogue component . and I meant that when I use this approach ,dialogue styling isn't proper and it's shifted to the bottom left and I don't understand why

Comment: @Omar, are you applying the encapsulation to the component opened by the modal or the one where you open the modal from? You should apply it to the one displayed by the modal. Not really sure, but you might have to encapsulate the styles in both. Again, without seeing an example I can't really help more.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-tree-1j35r?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/app/component/example.component.ts

some imports won't fit but u got a component where I use bootstrap and the dialogue component

Comment: @Omar, let me know when you cleaned all the imports and it's actually rendering. Right now it's broken and I'm not going to clean it up for you.